# manupulate url in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, url

On my page I have a lot of textpages and to save some time. I would like to make one controller/Action to handle all this sites. However, this gives me some problems with the URL (I dont want it to say something like http://MySite.com/DynamicPages/TextPages). I figure that I should be able to store all URL's in the database and then get the action to call from here.

I tried some differnt things and seached the web for solutions, but found nothing. Do anyone have some suggestions or know a article I can read about a solution.

Comment: What would you like your URLs to look like? Which part of the information in the URL be contained in a database?

Comment: The Urls could be something like Http://Mysite.com/articles/mvc. I would like to save the entire URL in the DB. That way I hope to be able to run multiple pages in the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found uot I could use the routes for what I wanted.